# Displaying the users according to the position in the database

Tags: php

I have a database with multiple users. Each user has an id, name and position. I want to display users by position. To take an example I have a table with 7 numbered positions.

Position          Name

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
```

And 4 users in the database that I want to display according to their position.

```
Name    Position
User_1  4
User_2  7
User_3  1
User_4  3
```

How can I do this without using the loop for or while for display?

I tried

```
for ($j=1; $j<=$no_rows; $j++){                             
    $rand = mysqli_fetch_array($tabel);
    $name[$j]=trim($rand['user']);
}
```

And then display for each number in that table that name[j].

Position Name

```
1. $name[1]
2. $name[2]
3. $name[3]
4. $name[4]
5. $name[5]
6. $name[6]
7. $name[7]
```

If those 4 users have positions 1,2,3,4, they are arranged by position, if one has the position higher than the total number of users then nothing is displayed, or it is displayed chaotically.
I also tried with j <= 7 but again the same problem.

Comment: `for` or `while` are not *functions*, and they are not *recursive*...

Comment: Is it possible to have empty positions like a donor rank or are positions always filled from top down like a leader board? Also how would you handle ties? This changes the answer significantly.

Comment: If you can without empty positions. Users are taken in ascending order.

Comment: PLease show us the schema for the table and a example of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question needs more info but here is a rough idea based on what you have so far and my making some assumptions that this is a leader board style list.

```
// Something like: $query = 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY point DESC';

$count = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_results_object))
{
  // Process data here.
  echo $count . ': ' . $row['username'];

  // Bail on 7.
  if ($count >= 7)
  {
    break;
  }
  $count ++;
}

// Fill in empty values.
while ($count < 7)
{
  echo $count . ': Space available.';
}
```

You did say without using the loop for display and your modified example appears to indicate you want rank instead of leader board position.

```
// Something like: $query = 'SELECT * FROM users';

$list = array_fill(1, 7, 'empty_value');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_results_object))
{
  // Process data here.
  $list[$row['rank']] = $row['name'];
}

echo $list[1];
echo $list[2]];
...
```

This would be very inefficient as if you had 100 users you would be adding all of them to an in-memory table only to display 7 of them. So make sure you query does something like: `SELECT TOP 7 * FROM users ORDER BY position DESC`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use loops in the display. It must be static. print $ row [1,2,3]. I have to somehow fill in that $ row from php if I don't have so many users in the database.

Comment: @RazvanDancea I update my answer with your updated question and example. It is very strange to not be able to loop inside your output. Are you sure that is a true requirement? Twig, phptemplate and other output engines do allow loops if you know how to do them.

Comment: I have the weird front end. is a tournament bracket. I want to select a maximum of 16 users, it depends a lot on the tournament, in this case I cannot put an output loop because it will not display correctly that bracket. It's easier for me to use something static. I am not so interested in the memory used.

Comment: My query $query= "SELECT * FROM `istoric_comp` WHERE comp_id='$tur_id' ORDER BY position_1 ASC";

Comment: @RazvanDancea my second code block should work perfectly for you then. I touched it up a bit.